# Почему нажимая на миниатюру открывается она , а не полное изображение

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>playstation</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.Window {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: 99999;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.Window:target {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.Window > div {
    width: 1030px;
    height:640px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 74px -50px;
    background-size:925px 640px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px;
    background-color:white;
}
.share{
    position:absolute;
    right-12px;
    top:52px;
    left:992px;
}
.fbshare{
    position:absolute;
    right:-12px;
    top:509px;
    left:992px;
}
.twshare{
    position:absolute;
    right:-12px;
    top:546px;
    left:992px;
}
a{
    float:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
.leftcol{
    width:200px;
    height:590px;
    float:left;
    background: url("images/lcolb.jpg") no-repeat;

}
.rigcol{
    width:45px;
    height:590px;
    float:right;
    background-color:white;

}
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    top:600px;
    background-color:black;
    width:1030px;
    height:50px;


}
.learn{
    position:relative;
    top:-58px;
    width:260px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0066cc;
    float:right;

}
.learnT{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
.learn:hover {background:#3399FF;}
.learn:hover a {color:#fff}
hr{
    background-color:black;
    position:fixed;
    top:462px;
    width:40px;
    height:1px;
    margin-left:3px;
    border:0;
}
.Tfind{
    margin-top:380px;
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
.Thorizont{
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    left:211px;
    color:white;
}
.hr2{
    width:1px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:200px;
    top:0px;
}
.hr3{
    width:170px;
    position:absolute;
    top:226px;
    left:5px;
}
.img1{
    margin-left:86px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.img1{
    margin-left:46px;
    margin-top:12px;
}
.img2{
    margin-top:89px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
.bgmain{
    width:785px;
    height:443px;
    margin-top:107px;
}
.button1{
    width:732px;
    height:90px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
.button2{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-left:8px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
.button3{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:7px;
    margin-top:16px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
.menu{
    width:200px;
    height:135px;
    margin-left:15px;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top:22px;
}
.nav {
    font: 12pt;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-left:9px;
    width:190px;
    height:45px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.nav li a {
    display:block;
    width:190px;
    height:45px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#fff;
    color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: all 0.6s linear;

}
.nav li a:hover{
    transform: scaleY(1.2);
}
.img3{
    margin-top:55px;
    margin-left:35px;

}
  .arrows{

 }
   .arrowleft{
    position: relative;
    left:2px;
    top:205px;
    width:3%;
    float:left;
}
.arrowright  {
    position:relative;
    top:205px;
    width:3%;
    float:right;
}
.arrowleft img{
    width:100%;
}
.arrowright img{
    width:100%;
}

.arrowleft img:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:95%;
}
.arrowleft img:active{
    width:85%;
}
.arrowright img:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:95%;
}
.arrowright img:active{
    width:85%;
}
.gallery__wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
}
.image-main__wrapper{

}
.image-main{
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 0;

}
.image-thumbnails__wrapper{
   width:785px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top:450px;

}
.thumbnails{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.thumbnails img{
    border: 2px solid dimgray;
    margin: 0px 1px 17px!important;

}
</style>
<script>
    function closeModal(){
    var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function showModal(){
    var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
<body>
<a href="#ModalOpen" title="">
<button type="button" class="button1" id="modal_close" 
onclick="showModal();">
        <img src="images/ban.jpg">
</button>
</a>
<div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
   <div class="content">
     <div class="gallery__wrapper">
        <div class="image-main__wrapper">
            <div class="arrows">
                <div class="arrowleft"><img src="images/left.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="arrowright"><img src="images/right.jpg"/></div>
            </div>
            <img class="image-main" src="images/fullsize/1.jpg">
            <div class="image-thumbnails__wrapper">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li><img id="thumb-1" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/1.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-2" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/2.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-3" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/3.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-4" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/4.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-5" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/5.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-6" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/6.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-7" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/7.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-8" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/8.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-9" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/9.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-10" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/10.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-11" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/11.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-12" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/12.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-13" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/13.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img id="thumb-14" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/14.jpg"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="leftcol">
        <img class="img1" src="images/ps4.jpg">
        <img class="img2" src="images/logo.jpg">
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab1" class="active">Video</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab2">Horizon Zero Dawn</a>
                    </br>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab3">Through Aloy's Eyes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-1">

        </div>
        <div id="tab-2">

        </div>
        <div id="tab-3">

        </div>

        <img src="images/esrb.jpg" class="img3"/>

    </div>
    <div class="rigcol">
        <button type="button" class="button2" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">
            <img src="images/x.jpg">
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="button3">
            <img src="images/share.jpg">
        </button>
        <hr>
        <p class="Tfind"> Find <br/>US ON</p>
        </hr>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fbshare">
            <img src="images/fb.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="twshare">
            <img src="images/twit.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <img src="images/i.jpg" class="img1">
        <hr class="hr2">
        <p class="Thorizont">Click on Horizon Zero Dawn to see the next era 
of mankind</p>
        <div class="learn">
            <p class="learnT"><a href="#learnmore">Learn More <strong> > 
</strong></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
(function() {
    var thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__img'),
        imageMain = document.querySelector('.image-main');
    var leftArrow = document.querySelector('.material-icons.left-btn'),
        rightArrow = document.querySelector('.material-icons.right-btn');
    var currentIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
        thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            imageMain.src = evt.target.src.replace('150/100', '1000/400');
            currentIndex = evt.target.id.substr(6, evt.target.id.length) - 1;
        });
    }
    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            currentIndex--;
            imageMain.src = thumbnails[currentIndex].src.replace('150/100', '1000/400');
        }
    });

    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        if (currentIndex < thumbnails.length -1) {
            currentIndex++;
            imageMain.src = thumbnails[currentIndex].src.replace('150/100', '1000/400');
        }
    });


})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`src.replace('150/100', '1000/400')` - не в одном из адресов картинок нет такого текста 150/100, по этому ему нечего заменить, и оно просто возвращает ту же строку без каких либо изменений.
Чтобы решить подобную проблему, лучше в дополнительном атрибуте у картинки дописать путь к полной картинке, и при клике на тамбнеил, брать этот урл из атрибута и вставлять в `imageMain`.

```
li><img id="thumb-1" class="gallery__img" src="images/1px.png" data-full-url="images/full/1.jpg"/></li>
<li><img id="thumb-2" class="gallery__img" src="images/1px.png" data-full-url="images/full/2.jpg"/></li>
<li><img id="thumb-3" class="gallery__img" src="images/1px.png" data-full-url="images/full/3.jpg"/></li>
<li><img id="thumb-4" class="gallery__img" src="images/1px.png" data-full-url="images/full/4.jpg"/></li>
```

а сам скрипт будет такой

```
function clickOnThumbnail(event) {
  imageMain.src = event.target.dataset.fullUrl;
}
for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
  thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click', clickOnThumbnail);
}
```

так же не стоит брать индекс изображения из url адреса, это очень не верно
лучше через `indexOf`, но при этом надо `thumbnails` превратить в массив из массивоподобного объекта, это делается через первую строку следующего кода

```
var thumbnails = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__img')),
function clickOnThumbnail(event) {
  imageMain.src = event.target.dataset.fullUrl;
  var indexOfImage = thumbnails.indexOf(event.target);
  console.log(indexOfImage);
}
```

Comment: значит старый скрипт удалить и вместо него это вставить или как ?

Comment: <li><img id="thumb-1" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/1.jpg"/></li>

Comment: function clickOnThumbnail(event) {
        imageMain.src = event.target.dataset.fullUrl;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
        thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click', clickOnThumbnail);
    }
    var thumbnails = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__img'))
        function clickOnThumbnail(event) {
        imageMain.src = event.target.dataset.fullUrl;
        var indexOfImage = thumbnails.indexOf(event.target);
        console.log(indexOfImage);
    }